# why is my ajax loading twice the same function?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to create a subscription form which basically let's you select a game, then load's a bunch of subscription prices for that game. Up to this point, everything works perfectly. The problem is, when I try to input 3 radio buttons to select payement for 1 month/ 6 months/ 1 year, the function that I call with ajax onchange="" in the dropdown seems to load twice, and the content is not accessed.

The first time, it works perfectly, it echo's the information, and calculates everything. but the second time, it just gives me a php error.

I've figured out what happens, it call's the function once, with the requested subscription price id (alert(planId);), and it echo's perfectly as I wanted it. Then it just calls the function again, but the alert(planId); returns me undefined, and echo's a new row (which was meant to happen) with the error code, saying that the sql request failed because of line 78.

Which brings me back to my question, why does AJAX call the function twice?

```
var xhr = {
    planData:function(){
        if (httpRequest.readyState==4) {
            if (httpRequest.status==200) {
                document.getElementById('plan_select').innerHTML = 'ready';
                var price = httpRequest.responseText;
                //alert(price);
                var six = 6*parseInt(price);
                var year = 12*parseInt(price);
                if (document.getElementById('diff')) {
                    var ctnt = '';
                    ctnt += '<input class="radio" type="radio" name="typeOfPlan" value="one" />&nbsp;';
                    ctnt += 'Month to month subscription plan ($'+price+' USD per month) &nbsp;';
                    ctnt += '<input class="radio" type="radio" name="typeOfPlan" value="six" />&nbsp;';
                    ctnt += 'Six months subscription plan ($'+six+' USD per 6 months) &nbsp;';
                    ctnt += '<input class="radio" type="radio" name="typeOfPlan" value="year" />&nbsp;';
                    ctnt += 'One year subscription plan ($'+year+' USD per year)';
                    document.getElementById('diff').innerHTML = ctnt;
                } else {
                    var yearPrices = document.getElementById('order').insertRow(3);
                    var cell = yearPrices.insertCell(0);
                    cell.id='diff';
                    cell.colSpan = 3;
                    var ctnt = '';
                    ctnt += '<input class="radio" type="radio" name="typeOfPlan" value="one" />&nbsp;';
                    ctnt += 'Month to month subscription plan ($'+price+' USD per month) &nbsp;';
                    ctnt += '<input class="radio" type="radio" name="typeOfPlan" value="six" />&nbsp;';
                    ctnt += 'Six months subscription plan ($'+six+' USD per 6 months) &nbsp;';
                    ctnt += '<input class="radio" type="radio" name="typeOfPlan" value="year" />&nbsp;';
                    ctnt += 'One year subscription plan ($'+year+' USD per year)';
                    cell.innerHTML = ctnt;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    updatePrice:function(planId){
        alert(planId);
        xhr.ajaxCall('GET', 'requests.php?action=getprices&planId='+planId, null, true, xhr.planData);
    },
    ajaxCall:function(method,url,postData,async,handler) {
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open(method,url,async);
        if (postData != null)
            httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","x-www-form-urlencoded");
        if (async)
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = handler;
        httpRequest.send(postData);
    }
};
```

This is the part of the code, you'll see the alert(planId); in the updatePrice function.

Here's a link to the actual working thing: http://www.nitroflox.com/temp/

Comment: do you have any code?  It'd be pretty handy to see your javascript here

Comment: im having a hard time figuring out how to post a reply

Comment: You have a problem with your code, you are even mentioning a certain line, but you don't post the code. You do you expect us to help you? Please edit your question and add the code.

Comment: got it, i was looking for the reply button

Comment: Hmm, another person who mistook SO for a forum. Pretty much, if you want to add any info to your question just edit it. If you want to reply to someone's answer add a comment.

Comment: cool :D, i didn't realize though =\

Comment: What function is being called twice? planData?

Comment: updatePrice actually, the alert happens twice there, first time it works, but then it gives undefined

Comment: @nitroflox - When I was editing your code for formatting, I noticed your first if statement did not have curly braces. I also added a curly brace at the end, as I'm sure you're closing it appropriately. When you're formatting your code, pay special attention to indention and readability, and that will help you see errors and other problems more easily.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the next time I post. Thanks again.

Comment: @nitroflox - That would be a general suggestion, not just for your posts here. I've gone through several iterations of code formatting over the years, and I know it really, really helps to have easily readable code with all the indentions spaced correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just looked at your supplied link. You are calling the updatePrice function twice:

```
onchange="xhr.updatePrice(xhr.updatePrice(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value))
```

Change to:

```
onchange="xhr.updatePrice(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: oh my, /facepalm  it worked, i'll read the code more next time. Thanks again.